# How to restrict push to specific users?

Tags: c#, git, selenium, tfs, azure-devops

I'm working with Git TFS 2015 with Gherkin method. So, we have manual testers who write feature file in Gherkin, and automation testers who implement these features in C#.

I would like to create some restrictions:

- Manual testers can only push feature files (*.feature, *.feature.cs)
- Automation testers can push anything, except feature files

How could I do that?

Comment: Git itself supports the concept of *hooks* and a `--bare` repository set up to receive pushes can have a *pre-receive* and/or an *update* hook that inspects commits and either accepts or rejects the push or the reference update. Writing such hooks is nontrivial but when done correctly, you can achieve this kind of control. Whether your TFS has some canned recipe, I don't know.

Comment: You can achieve it by pre-commit hook or pre-push hook. Is it the way you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That's not how Git works.

You can use branch policies to require a pull request for changes and reject any pull requests that contain changes that don't meet your criteria.